# How do I interpret this output from sklearn.tree.export_graphviz?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am working on analyzing grade data. As a new way to look at the data I am using a decision tree, for the first time. I believe I have the code right and now I am trying to interpret it. The features are grades gotten for a series of quizzes, and the classification is the final grade the student received. I have a few questions:

1. If my understanding is correct, each node has a test and a left branch representing the test being true, and the other for false. And when the tree seems to have asked enough questions, it says what the "class" is. If that is the case, how come there's a class= on boxes well before the leaves? I would have thought that just leaves have a class=
2. How do I "tune" the overall tree? It seems to have too many boxes. Is this an example of "overfitting"? How can I tune that better?
3. For example, the use of FINAL_GRADE_PA01 seems arbitrary to be based on the ordering of the data. Is that true or did the analysis actually conclude that that feature was the best discriminator?

[image]

Comment: Hi there. The community has discussed politenesses and niceties in posts, and has decided that we'd rather aim for brevity and a technical standard of writing. Thus, please refrain from adding thanks, greetings, salutations, etc. to posts. [Reference is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) on Meta.

Comment: Good job @halfer :)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, those `class` values indicate what the model would have predicted, had it stopped branching on that node. It still stores those values, but it doesn't use them if there's a branching from that node.

About the number of nodes, as you see in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html):

> The default values for the parameters controlling the size of the
>   trees (e.g. max_depth, min_samples_leaf, etc.) lead to fully grown and
>   unpruned trees which can potentially be very large on some data sets.
>   To reduce memory consumption, the complexity and size of the trees
>   should be controlled by setting those parameter values.

There are several parameters which you can use to reduce the *complexity* of your model. The following two parameters are just an example:

> **max_leaf_nodes** : int or None, optional (default=None)
>
> Grow a tree with max_leaf_nodes in best-first fashion. Best nodes are defined as relative reduction in impurity. If None then unlimited
>   number of leaf nodes.
>
> **min_impurity_decrease** : float, optional (default=0.)
>
> A node will be split if this split induces a decrease of the impurity greater than or equal to this value.